# How can I change the format of the date header of a column in FullCalendar v5?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want the `format of the date header` to be like "Monday 24" , "Tuesday 25" etc. however, right now the default for `FullCalendar` is "Mon 5/24", "Tue 5/25" etc. for the timeGridWeek. I am attaching how the UI currently looks like vs how I actually want it to look like along with the current code. How can I achieve this? I am referring to the documentation for `v5`, however it doesn't seem to be working fine on my end. Am I doing it wrong? Link to documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin],
      events: calendarEndpoint,
      initialView: "timeGridWeek",
      slotEventOverlap: false,
      views: {
        timeGridWeek: {
            titleFormat: {
                weekday: 'long',
            },
        },
    }

    });
    calendar.render();
```

***Alternative approach***

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin],
      events: calendarEndpoint,
      initialView: "timeGridWeek",
      headerToolbar : {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: ''
      },
      allDaySlot: false,
      slotEventOverlap: false,
      scrollTime: '08:00:00',
      weekday: 'long' 
      
    
    });
```

[image]

***That's how I want the format of column header to look like***

[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat - titleFormat is for the main title. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayHeaderFormat is for the column headers.

Comment: @ADyson I tried that as well, it didnt work! Have edited the question and added the code where I used weekday: 'long', but it didnt work

Comment: Weekday isn't an option. dayHeaderFormat is an option, and weekday is one of the sub settings within that. Not sure why you removed the view-specific bit either?

Comment: @ADyson yes, when I used dayHeaderFormat as an option it worked. thanks!